# Is it a good idea to run React application on Apache?

Tags: reactjs, apache

I know standard approach is to use node.js. However, our server side api is written on Apache. 
So, we wanted to run on Apache only.

1. Is it ok to run react on Apache or we need to install node js?
2. In apache setup, how do we do the .dotenv package? We need to set environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely fine to run React on Apache. Remember that "React" is nothing more than a JS framework/library. If your app is client-side rendered and you don't have to worry about server-side-rendering (SSR) then all you need is to deliver the bundle of JS (usually coming off Webpack) from your Apache server to the client.

Nodejs tends to be integrated nicely and hence used most of the time, but if you really want to stick to Apache only, then you can do it.

Read the official CRA [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing)

[This might also help](https://gist.github.com/ywwwtseng/63c36ccb58a25a09f7096bbb602ac1de)

Comment: Thanks a lot for validating. Do you know using the Apache server, how do i load environment variables in the application?  We want to build once and deploy to 15 servers. I have been told that it is only possible if you running node.js instead of apache

Comment: @Ash2 if you're using CRA you can do it straight from it as far as I know. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/. You can also try checking into Webpack variables, these will be available at build-time. 

Apart from that I don't know how to get Apache env variables into React, since Apache won't be building your app.